# Looking for an x509 certificate generator

Tags: windows, security

For development and local intranet purposes I am trying to find a decent and free x509 certificate generator.  I know there is makecert.exe which is available with the .NET Fx SDK, but I have tried using it and have run into seemingly inexplicable problems.

So are there any free and easy-to-use x509 cert generators which folks can recommend?

Comment: I assume you're looking for such software that runs on Windows?

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct: Windows.

Comment: I have always used [TinyCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyCA) for that, but a) I'm on Linux, b) I'm not sure whether it's available for Windows, and c) looks like the project has died (projectsite is gone, no update since ~2010 if I checked correctly). But it does its job for me. // Wikipedias [X.509](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) article mentions [SSLTools Manager for Windows](http://www.ssltools.com/manager) instead, might be worth a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [XCA](http://xca.sourceforge.net/) for this purpose. It's a complete GUI for managing certificates, keys, signing request and even a production-grade CA.

- Free and open source
- Multi-platform (Windows, Linux, Mac)
- Provides generation of private keys, self-signed certificates, signing request and CRLs
- Optionally used to manage a whole CA signing authority

I've used myself for testing and home use (nothing serious really), so I'm confident that it fits that purpose. Their site seems to indicate that it can also be used for production uses too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html). It will run on Windows.

Directions are [here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/HOWTO/certificates.txt).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966123/howto-create-a-certificate-using-openssl-including-a-crl-distribution-point) also shows how.

Comment: I hope they've fixed the Heartbleed thing!!!  :-)

Comment: @Cyberherbalist Yeah. :-)  If you get a new version, you'll be fine. It was a simple coding error. The big problem was folks have bad versions embedded into devices and servers that most don't think to update.